# JavaScript OR operator puzzle

Tags: javascript, jquery

My friend has posted a question on Javascript OR operator question.

I found it worth to share.

```
undefined || null || "" || NaN || "0" || 0 || Infinity || []
```

What should be the result of this expression and why?

Comment: What's the question? Do I need to watch the video (I can't)?

Answer (score 2):

> What should be the result of this expression and why?

You can easily try it out (JS console et al.), its the `"0"` string - the first non-falsy value in the evaluation of the expression. You might check out [this reference for logical operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators).

Comment: Thanks a lot Bergi, very useful reference..

Answer (score 1):

The result of the expression is "0", which can be determined using a Javascript console like this:

```
var result = undefined || null || "" || NaN || "0" || 0 || Infinity || [];
console.log(result);
```

This is because "0" is the first truthy value.